# Multiline match with irregular new line

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file with many entries like this:

```
[...]
Wind: 83,476,224
Solution: (category,runs)~
0.235,6.52312667,~
0.98962,14.33858333,~
sdasd,cccc,~
0.996052905,sdsd
EnterValues: 656,136,1
Speed: 48,32
State: 2,102,83,476,224
[...]
```

From above part I would like to extract:

```
Solution: (category,runs)~
0.235,6.52312667,~
0.98962,14.33858333,~
sdasd,cccc,~
0.996052905,sdsd
```

It would be simple if `EnterValues:` exists after every `Solution:`, unfortunately it doesn't. Sometime it is `Speed`, sometime something different. I don't know how to construct the end of regex (I assume it should be sth like this:`Solution:.*?(?<!~)\n`).

My file has \n as a delimiter of new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match from `Solution` to word followed by colon,

```
my ($solution) = $text =~ /(Solution:.*?) \w+: /xs;
```

Comment: TLP's solution also works, but yours is simpler and does what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I see you first read all file to memory, but this is not a good pracrice. Try use flip flop operator:

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
   if ( /Solution:/ ... !/~$/ ) {
      print $_, "\n";
   }
}
```

I can't test it right now, but I think this should work fine.

Comment: This solution requires you to know that `Solution` comes before either of the keywords.

Comment: @TLP, yes, but maybe it can be fixing by modifying the second regexp:)

Comment: @her_dom, yes, take a look at TLP's answer

Comment: Also, it will include the header for the next value in the print. A better regex to close the flip flip might be `/^\pL+:/`, but you still have to compensate for the extra line.

Comment: Dirty hack: add a boolean flag to skip first line:D And your closing regex looks good, thx. I will update an answer

Comment: No, flags are horrible. But if that tilde `~` is always on "continued" lines, you can do: `/^Solution:/ ... !/~$/`. But it will then only work for continued lines...

Comment: Your flip-flop will end right away, you must use `...` to disallow it from matching the same line twice. Also, your flag is wrong, since it prevents the first line to be printed, when it should prevent the last (which will be `EnterValues: 656,136,1`). You should try out the code before posting.

Comment: @TLP, As I said in my answer I can't try my code now. But thanks for corrections, next time I will not answer if I can't run my code before it

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to apply a "record separator" that has the functionality of a regex. Unfortunately, you cannot use `$/`, because it cannot be a regex. You can however read the entire file into one line, and split that line using a regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = do { 
    local $/;   # disable input record separator
    <DATA>;     # slurp the file
};
my @lines = split /^(?=\pL+:)/m, $str;  # lines begin with letters + colon
print Dumper \@lines;

__DATA__
Wind: 83,476,224
Solution: (category,runs)~
0.235,6.52312667,~
0.98962,14.33858333,~
sdasd,cccc,~
0.996052905,sdsd
EnterValues: 656,136,1
Speed: 48,32
State: 2,102,83,476,224
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Wind: 83,476,224
',
          'Solution: (category,runs)~
0.235,6.52312667,~
0.98962,14.33858333,~
sdasd,cccc,~
0.996052905,sdsd
',
          'EnterValues: 656,136,1
',
          'Speed: 48,32
',
          'State: 2,102,83,476,224
'
```

You will do some sort of post processing on these variables, I assume, but I will leave that to you. One way to go from here is to split the values on newline.

Comment: Could you explain what `\pL+` does? Can find it;/.

Comment: `\pL` is a character class for letters. `+` is the quantifier, meaning "match one or more times". You can find `\pL` in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html